# Two equal circles inscribed in a triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

Two equal circles are inscribed in a triangle as shown, with AC = 20 cm, AB = 13 cm and BC = 21 cm. Find the radius of the circle. I have no clue how it can be done except the drawing made in the diagram as shown. [Only Pythagoras theorem  and algebraic manipulations are allowed to be used]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered using angular identities?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Cut the circles vertically in half, then glue the figure back together as shown.
[image]

Now two circles merges into one, and the small triangle formed is similar to the original triangle, with a scale factor of $\frac {21-2r}{21}$ (why?)

The original triangle has area $126$ and perimeter $54$, hence its inradius is $\frac {14}3$.

Thus the new triangle has inradius

$$\frac {14}{3} \times \frac{21-2r}{21} = r$$

hence $r = \dfrac {42}{13}$.

Comment: Thank you, Can I know how do you know the vertical line that is perpendicular and intersecting BC is 5 cm from B? Next how do you find the inradius with the area and perimeter know?

Comment: I don't, it isn't, and I didn't use that. We have $A = pr/2$, where $p$ is perimeter, $r$ inradius and $A$ area.

Comment: @player3236 Interesting solution. Have you seen the problem [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119580/geometry)?

Answer (score 2):

The dimensions of the triangle were chosen to make this a little easier than it first appears.  The triangle can be divided to two Pythagorean triples..

[image]

The slope of the line from the B to the center of the closer circle is the same as the slope of the line from B to the incenter of the 5,12,13 right triangle.

There are a few ways to find this, but I like this one.

[image]

$a+b = 12\\
a+c = 13\\
b+c = 5$

Solving this system: $a = 10, b = 2, c = 3$

The slope is $\frac 23$
Doing the same to the $12,16,20$ triangle gives a slope of $-\frac 13$

[image]

$\frac 32 r + 2r + 3r = 21\\
r = \frac {42}{13}$

Comment: Wow! Finding $\tan \theta$ from $\tan 2\theta$ without using trig formulae! Pretty impressive :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b, c$ be the sides and note that

\begin{align}
a = 2r + r(\cot \frac{B}2 +\cot \frac{C}2)=2r + r\frac{\cos\frac A2}{\sin\frac B2 \sin\frac C2}\\
= 2r +r\frac{2R\sin A}{4R\sin\frac A2\sin\frac B2 \sin\frac C2}
= 2r +r \frac{a}{r_i}
\end{align}
with $R$ and $r_i$
the circumradius and inradius, respectively. Then,
$$ r = \frac{a}{2+\frac a{r_i}} = \frac{a}{2+\frac {a(a+b+c)}{2K}}
$$
where $K$ is the area of the triangle. Apply the Heron’s area formula to get
$$r= \frac a{ 2+\frac{a\sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}},\>\>\>\>\>
s=\frac{a+b+c}2$$
Substitute $a=21$, $b=20$ and $c=13$ to obtain $r=\frac{42}{13}$.

Answer (score 0):

***With trig:***

**Hint:** The cosine rule gives $$\cos A = \dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} \ \text{ where }a=BC,b=CA,c=AB$$ so you know all trigonometric values like $f(z)$ or $f(z/2)$ where $z$ is the angle $A,B$ or $C$, $f$ is one of the six trigonometric functions.

> **Further hint:** Note that $$BC = r\cot \frac{B}2 + 2r + r\cot \frac{C}2$$

***Without trig:***

**Hint:** Call the centers of the circles $B',C'$, with $B'$ closer to $B$.

 $BB' \cap CC' = I =$ incenter of $\triangle ABC$ 
Lengths of $BI,CI$ are known from applications of internal angle bisector theorem. Use similarity, and you might even be able to use the fact that $ID$ (where $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$) passes through the mutual touchpoint of the two circles.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask if there is any other method besides using cosine rule since angular identity is not allowed to be used. Pythagoras theorem is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the side $BC$ is the combination of three segments. One of them is directly related to the radius $r$. The problem is how to get the other two segments through trigonometry. 
Notice that this triangle ABC is a combination of two Pythagorean triangles. You can certainly get the values like $\sin$ and $\cos$ for these angles, then use the half-angle formula to express the segments in terms of $r$, then you are done, because you can express $BC$ as a multiple of the radius $r$.

Answer (score 0):

The area of the whole triangle can be found using Heron's formula: the semiperimeter $s$ is $\frac{1}{2}(13+20+21) = 27$, and $A = \sqrt{27(27-13)(27-20)(27-21)} = 126$. The altitude of the triangle from the $21$ cm base is thus $\frac{126}{1/2 \cdot 21} = 12$.

Now rearrange the area of the triangle to form three smaller triangles with bases $13, 20$ and $21-2r$ and heights of $r$, and a right-angled trapezoid in the centre. This has area $\frac{1}{2}r(13+20+21-2r) + \frac{1}{2}(2r)(12+r)$.

Equating the two forms of the area, we have $r(54 - 2r) + 2r(12+r) = 252$, or $-2r^2+54r+24r+2r^2=252$. Hence $r = \boxed{\frac{42}{13}}$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Triangle ABC]

Let the centres of the circles be $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$. The segments $BC_{1}$ and $CC_{2}$,when extended, meet at $I$ , the incentre of $\triangle ABC$. Circle $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ touch the side $BC$ at points $E$ and $F$ respectively. The incircle of $\triangle  ABC$ touches the side $BC$ at point $D$. Draw $C_{1}E$, $C_{2}F$, $C_{1}C_{2}$ and $ID$. Let $ID$ intersect $C_{1}C_{2}$ at point $L$. Let the radii of the similar circles and the inradius of $\triangle ABC$ be $r'$ and $r$ respectively.

$\triangle IC_{1}C_{2}\sim \triangle IBC$ because $C_{1}C_{2}\parallel BC$.

$\Rightarrow  \frac{C_{1}C_{2}}{BC}=\frac{IL}{ID}$

$\Rightarrow   \frac{2r'}{21}=\frac{r-r'}{r}$

$\Rightarrow   r'=\frac{ar}{2r+a}=\frac{21r}{2r+21}$

Use $\Delta=rs$ to get $r$ and then plug it into the equation to get $r'$.